# Remote Download Manager on Windows

Tags: windows, remote-access, download-manager

I need a download manager that supports remote control like uTorrent client on Windows 8.

I have a PC running Windows 8 at home and I want to add download links when I am at work remotely onto my home PC so that they'll be downloaded ready for me to access when I get home..

I tried mipony 2.1.3 . Every thing was great except the that "link detection" feature on the "web interface" didn't work for me.

Is there another download manager out there that supports:

- Full remote control
- Download resumption/pausing
- Download prioritization
- Download threading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found **Jdownloader 2.0** useful for controlling downloads from remote computers.

Remember that Jdownloader 2.0 is a beta version of Jdownloader and the stable release of Jdownloader doesn't has all of the features of a remote download manager.

It is just like uTorrent and has Firefox and Chrome Add-on to add download links to remote download manager and to manage remote download manager just in your browser.

You can log in to [my.jdownloader.org](http://my.jdownloader.org) and add your remote download manager IP& prot and then manage your Jdownloader Remotely

Comment: I took the recommendation of installer JDownloader for the same use as the original requester asked. Avoid it, it installs malware with the software and you'll end up getting spammed in your browser with advertising from the malware

Comment: For the record, there are clean installers that are adware free as alternatives, see this forum post for details: https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?t=54725

Answer (score 1):

Now that I'm on a reliable highspeed internet I don't actually use a download manager - Firefox can do it fine and I don't need any of the features of a full fledged download manager. Sure I could have some downloads faster but when I can download QTP (Qarl's Texture Pack - an TES IV: Oblivion Mod) in a matter of minutes I don't need that. However when I was on dialup a download manager was an absolute requirement. My recommended Download Manager would be [FreeDownloadManager (FDM)](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/features.htm). As well as on the standard download manager things (ie resuming, multi-part downloading etc.) FDM also support torrent protocols (which is really handy for downloading ArchiCAD on a crud connection)*.

I haven't used the FDM remote control function but as FDM has a great user interface for everything else I'm sure it will have a good interface there at minimum.

*: not pirating which I don't recommend but Graphisoft (the developer) offers a torrent as an official method of downloading.