# Windows download manager with a Web GUI for playing videos

Tags: windows, web-apps, video, gui, download-manager

I am looking for a (free or paid) Windows download manager that has a Web UI for adding, pausing, and playing video.

I know there is a similar post [Remote Download Manager on Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/remote-download-manager-on-windows), however, that does not solve my problem since the solution like MyJDownloader does not have the option to add downloads, one can only add links but there is no option to add links to the download queue.

The Web UI for the download manager I am looking for should:

1. Resume and pause downloads
2. Add new downloads (most important)
3. Progress of download

NB: on a Windows platform.

I am open to **free PHP scripts** suggestions that can download a YouTube video. Bearing in mind the YouTube video download links do not have a file extension binding at the end.

Comment: why web ui? why not native software?

Comment: I have slow connection at my local computer hence I want to use my faster VPS remote computer to temporarily keep downloads with download links that have urls that expire(not suitable for slow internet when files are big)

Comment: So you want to self-host a Web app that can download (and play) videos, right? In which way would that have to interact with Windows? Couldn’t you just use any browser, log into the Web app and download the videos from your server?

Comment: @Jamesup whats your vps? linux or windows? if linux you can ssh to it and then use rsync or dropbox, if windows, you can login to it normally, download files using a native software such as eagleget and place them inside dropbox or whatever

Comment: Playing videos not really.I just want to convert that temporary link to permanent.Since i can easily use a ftp to download directly which is relatively faster for me. The VPS is windows hence if the needing a windows download manager unless there is a good standalone php script.

Comment: @Lynob I am looking for a simpler solution since i browse on my local computer then find something I like to download.Then hopefully open a  tab add my link and it starts Downloading.Open another tab see the downloaded file click on it it downloads,Or just using ftp client.

Comment: https://licson.net/post/create-a-youtube-video-downloader-in-php/

Comment: @Lynob I will checkout the script and report back if it works.However I would still like the download manager option since Youtube Is not the only site with temporary download links.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this massive list on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers) with all download managers (yeah, all of them, some are like 20 years old).

http://www.freedownloadmanager.org

Anyways it looks like `Free Download Manager` fits you best.
According to their website all of the features you need are listed.

Plus it is open source and free.

Pro tip: to use the web server you need to open a seperate program (you can find it in your start menu, it's called something like `FDM Server`)

Comment: Unfortunately when you download FDM and install it.The remote control server does not work.The server folder just has bunch of html files that do nothing:https://github.com/JackieKu/fdm/tree/master/setup/Free%20Download%20Manager/Server      I have been checking the list and downloading the ones listed and remote control, I will report back which one works best.