# Remote Download Manager with Browser Plugin support

Tags: web-browser, download-manager

I am looking for a way to direct typical download file on a web browser to a remote server without having to keep the local computer on.

I did come across certain browser plugins that allows me to do this, but it requires me to send download link for it to work. For certain download sites, it is just not possible to know the exact download link until the download has started. Once the download has started, the same download link cannot be reused again.

Comment: Although I don't know what platform you want to do this with, some similar remote control operations for windows are found at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/remote-download-manager-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: I saw that post before. I think it only introduces solution for local computer. I need more of a server solution. Also, I need a browser plugin integration, so I can browse the internet on the local computer and is able to forward the download to a remote server. By the way, I have both Windows and Linux servers, so either would work.